# do not want to automatically change all references for a table rename in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, reference, rename

Is there a way to turn off functionality in MS Access that if i rename a table, it DOESNT change all references to that table in other queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there is a feature called AutoCorrect in MS Access. You Simply have to turn this off:

"options" -> "current database" -> unselect "Track name AutoCorrect info"